# What's an expression meaning too drunk to remember what happened?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What's a British English term (slang or casual) for having forgotten events due to being drunk or stoned?

Comment: Please include an example sentence that would use this word.

Comment: 'Can't remember a thing,' he said gaily. 'It's all -----.'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure how 'casual' this is, but

**blackout**.

> a period of total memory loss, as one induced by an accident or prolonged alcoholic drinking:
>   *The patient cannot account for the bizarre things he did during his blackout.*
> -[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blackout?s=t)

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember a thing. It's all gone; blank; lost; wiped; blotto…

Please consider also: I can't remember a thing… I was off my head; off my face; out of it; wasted; gone; smashed; legless; plastered; dead; blotto